# smooth scroll to a anchor tag and focus on the first field form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html form in a page, bunch of text and a anchor tag to the form at the end of the page. Right now the action is very abrupt.

I want to the following two things.

1. Make the scroll from bottom of the page to the top smooth ( I looked some javascript options but they didn't work).
2. When the scroll happens I want it focus on the first field in the form (first name field)

HTML field:

```
<form id="register">
<label for="Name"><strong> Your Name:</strong></label>
<input type="text" id="Name_First" name="Name_First" required>
<input type="text" id="Name_Last" name="Name_Last" required>   

<label for="Email">Email Address:</label>
<input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" vrequired>

<label for="RegPassword">Password:</label><input type="password" id="RegPassword" name="RegPassword" required>
<form>  

<a href="#register"> Fill out the form </a></p>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/co1ot6ru/

Is there a way I can do that? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On click, [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) scroll the body to the top and, when complete, [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus) on the first an input.

```
$('a[href="#register"]').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); 

    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "0px" }, 1000, function(){

        $('input#Name_First').focus();

    });   

});
```

In jQuery, you can select based on the value of an attribute, like so `a[href="#register"]`

You have to `focus()` when the animation completes or both fire at the same time and the page jumps

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/co1ot6ru/7/)

Comment: Im aware and will remove if it turns out that vanilla Javascript is desired. I asked in the comments with no reply so I decided not to wait to post

Comment: I wouldn't either. Correct answer credit favors haste!

Comment: Hey! I am/was open to using jquery or plain vanilla javascript. The one Brian suggested works fine in fiddle.I believe there is some sort of interference in my code, it is failing. Thanks anyway for your code snippet. That seems to do what I wanted.

Comment: It works. Turns out I was mis-spelling a variable name.